# Jasmine - How to spy on a function call within a function and again within a function on controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit tests for angular controller written in coffee script and I have problem with understanding why some tests are passing even if they shouldn't and why some are not.

This is  my controller:

**add_user_controller.coffee**

```
(->
class AddUserController
  @$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'OfficesService', 'UserFactory']

  constructor: (@$scope, @$http, @$state, @OfficesService, UserFactory) ->
    @offices = @OfficesService
    @user = new UserFactory()

  save: ->
    self = this

    @user.save().then ->
      self.$state.go('app.main.users.list')

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('AddUserController', AddUserController)
)()
```

These are my tests:

**add_user_controller.test.coffee**

```
'use strict'

describe 'Controller: AddUserController', ->
    AddUserController = null
    scope = {}
    http = {};
    state = {
      go: (value) ->
        bar = value
    }
    OfficesService = {};
    UserFactory = null
    q = null

  # Initialize the controller and scope
  beforeEach ->
    # Load the main module
    module 'app'

    inject ($rootScope, $controller, _UserFactory_, $q) ->
      UserFactory = _UserFactory_
      q = $q
      scope = $rootScope.$new
      AddUserController = $controller 'AddUserController',
        $scope: scope,
        $http: http,
        $state: state,
        OfficesService: OfficesService,
        UserFactory: UserFactory

  it 'should call "save" on "user"', ->
    deferred = q.defer()
    spyOn(AddUserController.user, "save").and.returnValue deferred.promise
    AddUserController.save()
    expect(AddUserController.user.save).toHaveBeenCalled

  it 'should move to the "app.main.users.list" after "save" method has been called', ->
    spyOn(AddUserController.$state, "go")
    AddUserController.save()
    expect(AddUserController.$state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('app.main.users.list')
```

## FIRST PROBLEM

Test `'should call "save" on "user"'` is passing even if I comment following lines in controller:

```
#    @user.save().then ->
#       self.$state.go('app.main.users.list')
```

## SECOND PROBLEM

Test `'should move to the "app.main.users.list" after "save" method has been called'` is failing with:

> Expected spy go to have been called with [ 'app.main.users.list' ] but
>   it was never called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript's syntax but what it looks like to me is that you set your spy on the wrong function in the first one. Try this:

```
spyOn(UserFactory, "save").and.returnValue deferred.promise
```

For the second one, I think your spy for `$state`is set correctly but you need to trigger the digest cycle any time you are waiting for a promise to be returned. If it were me, I would move the spy for `UserFactory.save()` and your deferred variable into the `beforeEach()`. Then in both test try adding

```
deferred.resolve();
scope.$digest() // or scope.$apply()
```

after your call to `AddUserController.save()`. Hope this is helpful.